# How to send email using gmail oAuth using PHP?

Tags: php, oauth, gmail

**How to send email using gmail oAuth using PHP?**

I'm using three-legged.php file and able to get inbox using IMAP (file is using this as default). But I want to use auth for sending mail. Not able to get it working. Can you please suggest.

Thanks, 
Prashant

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean SMTP Auth not OAuth, they are 2 entirely different things ;-)

See PHPMailer and the excellent example they give...

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I certainly understand SMTP. But I wanted to use oAuth for sending mail from gmail.

There is something missing in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602680/how-to-implement-gmail-oauth-api-to-send-email-especially-via-smtp thread.

This is what i wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHPMailer. It's an excellent class.

Refer [This](http://www.vulgarisoip.com/?p=17)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18735