# Access emails for gmail with oauth

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail

I am able to get access token from gmail using OAuth in my application.

Now I want to access emails from gmail using OAuth Access token and not by providing User name and password.

I want to read new mail, send mail etc.

can you please help me with some sample code in c# that how could I read new mail, send, reply etc.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Gmail OAuth API to send email (especially via SMTP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602680/how-to-implement-gmail-oauth-api-to-send-email-especially-via-smtp)

Comment: Not a dupe - the tag indicates it's a C# based question.  The linked question is for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Mail.dll supports OAuth out-of-the-box:

http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth-with-imap

[Please note that this is a commercial product I created]